# Uninstall vagrant on Mac

Tags: macos, vagrant, osx-elcapitan

I want to uninstall Vagrant on a mac running El Capitan.

The Vagrant docs say:

> On Mac OS X, remove the /Applications/Vagrant directory and the /usr/bin/vagrant file. Also execute sudo pkgutil --forget com.vagrant.vagrant to have OS X forget that Vagrant was ever installed.

However, there is no `/Applications/Vagrant` directory, and there's no `/usr/bin/vagrant` file:

```
➜  ~  ls /usr/bin/va*
zsh: no matches found: /usr/bin/va*
➜  ~  ls /Applications/Vagrant
ls: /Applications/Vagrant: No such file or directory
```

I've reinstalled Vagrant 1.7.4 just to make sure that it's actually there, and I can verify:

```
➜  ~  vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.7.4
```

Any idea what's up? Are the docs just out of date?

Comment: how did you install ? with a package manager like homebrew ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri-- I installed using the Vagrant installer.

Comment: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/uninstallation.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Download the installer again.  In there is an uninstall script called uninstall.tool

Run the uninstaller from terminal: ./uninstall.tool

Comment: If anyone here who installed via homebrew, you can uninstall it just like any other package: `brew uninstall vagrant`

Comment: Error: No available formula with the name "vagrant"

Answer (score 16):

Use this on Mac osX

```
rm -rf /Applications/Vagrant
rm -f /usr/local/bin/vagrant
sudo pkgutil --forget com.vagrant.vagrant
rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d
```

Answer (score 8):

The Vagrant team has published detailed instructions for all platforms:

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/uninstallation.html

> On Mac OS X:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /opt/vagrant /usr/local/bin/vagrant
sudo pkgutil --forget com.vagrant.vagrant
```

Comment: This is the acceptable answer as of May 2019.

Just in case you need to run the `./unistall.tool`  with sudo or just need to examine it, when you click on the vagrant dmg file you downloaded and the application installation box is launched, you can navigate to the uninstall.tool with your terminal. `cd /Volumes/Vagrant`

Answer (score 5):

Use this instructions for Linux:

```
rm -rf /opt/vagrant
rm -f /usr/bin/vagrant
```

Comment: Helped me.  After
```
rm -rf /Applications/Vagrant
rm -f /usr/local/bin/vagrant
sudo pkgutil --forget com.vagrant.vagrant
rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d
``` 
still had vagrant available.